# Can an external process call the dotnet WebApplicationFactory test server?

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

I'm trying to write some end-to-end integration tests for Stripe webhooks, using the Stripe CLI to listen to an endpoint when events occur within the test environment.

What I would like to do have contained integration tests within our solution, that can be run by standard `dotnet test` commands, so that the tests can become part of our CI process.

What I was thinking was during the test setup process:

- Instantiate new WebApplicationFactory
- C# Unit Test invokes Stripe CLI tool with listen flag using Process.Start. Continue the process running until test finishes during a tear down
- CLI tool calls the http://localhost endpoint exposed by the WebApplicationFactory (is this endpoint even accessible outside of the test process?)

Is this all possible from within dotnet testing project? Or do I need a custom test script that runs the API project containing the endpoint, starts the Stripe CLI listen tool pointing to the API project, and have my test cases point to the running API as opposed to using the standard method of testing controllers with the WebApplicationFactory?

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: I'd generally suggest not introducing a dependency on a third party service(Stripe) being up and available for your CI to be able to run, it's generally better to mock things out.

Comment: Yes, we are using mocks for some of our testing, however this is for automated integration testing.

Comment: Did you find out the answer? I am wondering the same issue. My docker needs to do healthcheck on my integration test.